# Establishing MTP connection for Android Studio

Tags: usb-debugging, mtp

I am trying to connect an Android device to my PC in order to use it to test an app created with Android Studio. After connecting the device, I don't get the usual USB connection notification on my device and nothing shows up in my PC's file manager either.

I tried using both my Honor 5x (Android 6) and Nexus 9 (Android 7) as well as Windows 10 and Elementary OS and multiple ports/USB cables. On the Nexus 9, I enabled the developer options and set the connection mode to MTP.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio needs a device connected in ADB not MTP, though MTP can be activated with no effect.

On the device:

- Open the Developer options
- Enable USB debugging.
- You  need to install drivers for the device to get detected by the PC.

On the PC, Android Studio:

- **Alt + F10**  should open a window showing your device connected

Then you'll be able to test apps build with Android Studio

Comment: I did that, but am still not getting a connection. The tablet is not showing up in android studio or the file manager and there is also no notification on the tablet itself, however it is charging.

Comment: Defective cable probably? Did you try another USB cable? or the USB port may be damaged, may have dust, debris, etc

Comment: Hm I tried different ports on my laptop and two different cables, I will try a different PC when I have access to one. Thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: If all this doesn't work, you need to check for drivers! Without drivers your device will never be detected !

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on the Developer Mode ON on your Android device, and allowed USB Debugging; and does your PC have proper device drivers installed?  Check whether ADB is working or not.  If the problem persists then you need to uninstall everything and reinstall things in the sequence required, like first installing Java, and then ADB, and then Android Studio, and then setting up your Android Device as developer mode with USB Debugging allowed.